# Get SVN diff between branches up to a certain revision

Tags: svn, diff, revision

I am creating a new branch for each release in my SVN root such as :

```
/tags/release-1
/tags/release-2
```

I'd like to get a diff of all files between the 2 branches up to a given release.

I'm OK getting the diff without the revision using:

```
svn diff --summarize /tags/release-1 /tags/release-2
```

However if additional changes are made to /tags/release-2 for some likely undesired reason, I only want to pull the changes up to a certain revision. So for instance I was hoping for a command such as:

```
svn diff -rBASE:53 --summarize /tags/release-1 /tags/release-2
```

Which is a bit of a guess on my part, but hopefully you can see what I'm trying to accomplish. This however gives the error:

```
svn: Summarizing diff can only compare repository to repository
```

The next step for my deployment process would then be to export all the changed files based on their given revision so I can guarantee what code changes reside within that particular deployment.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that what you want to tell with `BASE` is `HEAD` instead (i.e. `-rHEAD:53`), you want to compare the latest version in release-1 with a particular version in release-2, not the one checked out.